# ASP.NET button always goes to server even if return false in js onclick function first

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="delete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

When clicking the button it goes into the JavaScript function, but still goes to the btnDelete_Click event in the code-behind. How can I prevent this... I only want it to post to the server if I return true. I tried with jQuery instead of OnClientClick I just used the jQuery OnClick w/ e.preventDefault(); and still always goes to server...

```
function delete() {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but I believe that you have to `return` the value of the function inline:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return delete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use "**return**" while calling the javascript function

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return delete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```